# How to save a decision flow chart as xml

Tags: xml

I am using as3 flashbuilder

thanks in advance

I want to save data in this diagram as an xml file.

[image: Diagram]

This is my try but I didn't like it. What the best program to deal in xml with tree like?

```
<Troubleshooting>
    <POWER OK>
        <yes name="POWER SEATED">
            <yes name="IS 110 VOLT"></yes>
            <no name="CHANGE IT"></no>
        </yes>
        <no name="DATA IN SCREEN">
            <yes name="RETRY BOOT"></yes>
            <no name="VIDEO FALURE"></no>
        </no>
  </POWER OK>
</Troubleshooting>
```

Comment: Edited but I dont think the xml is valid

Comment: Smells very much like the same again as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091912/i-want-to-save-decision-data-in-xml-file-data

Comment: What didn't you like about it, other than the fact that your `<POWER OK>` is not legal XML and, conceptually, should actually be merged into the Troubleshooting element as `<Troubleshooting name="POWER OK">` -- and I'd change "name" to "message" since you're using it both for questions and for answer leaves. Of course there are many other possible approaches, but the real answer is going to be "what's easiest for your programs to handle"? Just as with any other data structure design question.